# search and count entries in a table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Alarm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Missing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to count the rows in this table like this
OK = 2
Missing = 1

But I have no idea how to do it with jQuery, the selector should be specified just for alarm columns because I have other columns contains ok and missing

**Note:** I want to count the rows for specific column in the table just for alarms column
alaram columns contains 2 ok and 1 missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming `Alarm` is the first column:

```
var okCount = $('td:contains("OK")').filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() == 0;
}).length;
var missingCount = $('td:contains("Missing")').filter(function() {
    return $(this).index() == 0;
}).length;

console.log('okCount: ' + okCount);
console.log('missingCount : ' + missingCount);​
```

[**​Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2aXr/2/)

Comment: @epascarello, and what is not correct in it? though you almost said it all in your comment... NOT.

Comment: There is nothing in the post about multiplying by two. The 2 in the code is the result the poster was after.

Comment: @epascarello, ohhh, not I got what he meant, thanks I edited.

Comment: Your code is still wrong, I believe someone edited their original post, it is only for the "alarm" column.

Comment: @epascarello, mmm, now it should be fine.

Comment: @gdoron Hear that? You're a rock ;)

Answer (score 4):

See if this does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/AG6kr/

```
var table = document.getElementById('yourTableID'),
    column = 1,
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    trLen = tr.length,
    numMissing = 0,
    numOK = 0;


while(trLen--) {
    if(tr[trLen].children[column-1].innerHTML == 'OK') {
        numOK++;
    }
    if(tr[trLen].children[column-1].innerHTML == 'Missing') {
        numMissing++;
    }
}

console.log(numOK);
console.log(numMissing);
```

in case anybody wanted to know how to do it sans jQuery

Comment: There we go, refer to this one instead of my answer. This counts only those values in the 'Alarm' header.

Answer (score 1):

Who needs jQuery?

```
var table = document.getElementById('yourTableID'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    numCells = cells.length,
    okCount = 0,
    missingCount = 0;

while(numCells--) {
    if (cells[numCells].innerHTML == 'OK') okCount++;
    else if (cells[numCells].innerHTML == 'Missing') missingCount++;
}

console.log('OK: ' + okCount + ', Missing: ' + missingCount);    // Should output "OK: 2, Missing: 1 into the console
```

Comment: @gdoron, You also for get the 32kb that goes along with it. :)

Comment: @gdoron Indeed! Now *technically*, prof did ask for a jQuery solution, but just for the sake of completion, here's a non-jQueryified solution.

Comment: @epascarello, I'm afraid I didn't get that joke, sorry.

Comment: I believe he's referring to the overhead incurred by loading the jQuery library. Mostly, it's a non-issue, but it is there...

Comment: @gdoron jQuery is not free, you downloaded 32kb of JavaScript so you could write it in one line.

Comment: The code is wrong, I believe someone edited their original post, it is only for the "alarm" column.

Comment: @epascarello, 32K is almost nothing, the pictures that any site have are a lot more than 32K, and the jQuery is most probably cached in the browser as you well know. but.. if you don't like jQuery... you can write more.

Comment: @epascarello Hm, you're right... I didn't catch that on the first read-through.

Comment: It is a simple `%` check in your loop.

Comment: that's cool but i want to count the rows for the specific column alarams

Comment: If the only reason you were using jQuery was to solve this problem, it would indeed be overkill. But if your application is already using jQuery for other purposes, there's little extra overhead to using it for this.

Answer (score 1):

no need for filter for the index, use an nth-child selector! Also my selectors use thead and tbody, it would fail on the example used in the OP's code.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Alarm</th>
            <th>Warning</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>OK</td>
            <td>OK</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Missing</td>
            <td>Missing</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>OK</td>
            <td>OK</td>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var index = $("table thead th:contains('Alarm')").index() + 1;  //index is zero based, nth-child is 1 based.
var cells = $("table tbody td:nth-child(" + index + ")");

var okCount = cells.filter(":contains('OK')").length;
var missingCount = cells.filter(":contains('Missing')").length;

console.log(okCount, missingCount);
```

​
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puYqf/)

Comment: +1 nice one. though I hate all those index css selectors, I fall in the 0\1 index base every time!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PzBqX/4/

For the sake of overkill, this is in case you had the same table structure and wanted to search ANY column for ANY set of data.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Alarm</th>
    <th>Fruit</th>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>OK</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Missing</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>OK</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    var results = tallyResults($('table'), 'Fruit', Array('Apple', 'Orange'));

    /*
       {
           Apple: 2,
           Orange: 1
       }
    */
});


function tallyResults(table, col, vals) {
    var valsCount = { }
    var columnIndex = null;

    //-- init value object using vals array

    $(vals).each(function(i, v) {
        valsCount[v] = 0;
    });

    //-- get index of the column we are currently searching

    table.find('tr th').each(function(i, v) {
        el = $(this);
        if (el.text() == col) {
            columnIndex = el.index();
        }
    });


    //-- tally all instances of the values we are searching
    //-- for in the proper column index

    table.find('tr td').each(function(i, v) {
        el = $(this);
        if (el.index() == columnIndex) {
           t = el.text();
           if(valsCount[t] != undefined) {
              valsCount[t]++;
           }
        }
    });


    return valsCount;
}
```

Comment: I liked how the answer was in it's previous state, you know, it reminds me an answer I saw once...

Comment: Great minds stink alike! Granted, we both missed the Alarm stipulation as well. I figured I would make up for coming up with the same answer with this.

Comment: Yeah... right. You had the same names and spaces and quotes.. you just copied it!

Comment: corrected it* It was prior to you fixing your little math issue. Your latest solution is much better. Hence being marked as the answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

`$('td:contains("OK")').length`
Will return the number of cells that contain "OK"

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/tQTDk/9/

```
var points = 0;

$("td").each(function() {

    var tdVal = $(this);

    if(tdVal.text().indexOf('OK') >= 0)
       points += 2;


    if(tdVal.text().indexOf('Missing') >= 0)
       points += 1;
});

alert(points);
```

​

Comment: This doesn't count the alarm header problem. and `val` is a bad naming choice I think. and I fell in the points too, by OK -2 he meant there are two ok in the tables.