# How to row count of duplicate cell values on a HTML5 Table using java-script or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have a basic HTML Table with 2 columns (Id & Status). On 'Status' column, cell values are coming as 'Live' or 'Dead'. I want to count how many rows having 'Live' values and how many have 'Dead' values

```html
<table id="active-users" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Live</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>Dead</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>Live</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This data coming from php or what?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are expected to make an effort yourself _before_ you come asking here. This is not a code-writing service, where you just drop off your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
let livecount = $("table td:contains('Live')").length;
let deadcount = $("table td:contains('Dead')").length;
console.log("Live: " + livecount + ", Dead: " + deadcount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="active-users" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Live</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>Dead</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>Live</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @BhabaniShankarDash Glad that I was able to help. If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to resolve your question as answered/solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jquery to read through all of the table rows in your table and keep a counting if the value matches the search string.

Take a look at [escasparello's answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481460/search-and-count-entries-in-a-table-jquery). They provide a few lines of Jquery that should do the trick.